# make tab to act as a link in element ui

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, element-ui

I'm working with element ui, and I have a tabs element, I want one of the tabs to act like a link and not a tab, for example:

[image]

I want when I click on External link to open a link in a new browser tab, but I don't want it to act like a tab, meaning, when I'm on User tab and then I click on External link, the user tab will be always the shown one, and not to hide it and then select the External link tab.

I tried to add a el-link element inside the tabs element but it doesn't work like that, so I think the External link should be kept as el-tab-pane and then to omit it's behaviour which is to show the content of the tab and select it, but I have no idea how to do that.

This is my code:

```
<el-tabs v-model="activeName" @tab-click="handleClick">
    <el-tab-pane label="User" name="first">User</el-tab-pane>
    <el-tab-pane label="Config" name="second">Config</el-tab-pane>
    <el-tab-pane label="External link" name="third"></el-tab-pane>
  </el-tabs>
```

This is the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/z2g53bs1/6/

If you guys have any ideas or a solution I would be grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not using vue.js, but you could simply add an `<a>`nchor element to the `<el-tabs>`. Or if Vue has an alternative to `<a>`, use that...(with the necessary CSS eye-candy, of course)

Comment: @RenevanderLende I'm afraid it's not that simple, if you do that, the anchor element will be considered as a content  for the tabs and not a tab header.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to customize the content of the `tab-pane` element label using slots - https://element-plus.org/#/en-US/component/tabs#tab-pane-slots

This way you can the `a` tag inside it. Still won't solve prevent changing the active tab to the `External link`. You could add a disabled flag to the `el-tab-pane` and customize the style.

```
<template>
  <el-tabs v-model="activeName" @tab-click="handleClick">
    <el-tab-pane label="User" name="first">User</el-tab-pane>
    <el-tab-pane label="Config" name="second">Config</el-tab-pane>
    <el-tab-pane label="External link" name="third">
      <template #label>
        <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">External link</a>
      </template>
    </el-tab-pane>
  </el-tabs>
</template>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use to handleClick to forward you to a new page:

```
   watch: {
    activeName(newValue, oldValue) {
       if (newValue == 'third') {
         window.open("https://www.google.com", "_blank")
         this.activeName = oldValue
       }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Sorry but this will just open a link when clicking on the tab, but I don't want the tab to be selected when clicking on it, neither to show it's content.

Comment: Updated the answer, but the basic stays the same, but instead use a watch